# Can't run sudo command in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am writing an Ansible playbook to automate a series of sudo commands on various hosts. When I execute these commands individually in puTTY, I have no permission problems, as I have been granted proper access. However, when I attempt to create a playbook to do the same thing, I am told

> user is not allowed to execute ... on host_name

For example, if I do `$ sudo ls /root/`, I have no problem, and, once I enter my password, can see the contents of /root/

In the case of my Ansible playbook ...

```
---
- host: servers
  tasks:
  - name: ls /root/
    shell: ls /root/
    become: true
    become_method: sudo
```

...I then get the error mentioned above.

Any ideas why this would be the case? It seems to be telling me I don't have permission to run a command that I otherwise could run in an individual puTTY terminal.

Comment: Post `-vvv` ansible logs.

Answer (score 1):

> [ ] automate a series of sudo commands on various hosts. When I execute these commands individually [ ]
>
> Any ideas why this would be the case?

Sounds like you configured specific commands in the `sudoers` file (unfortunately you did not provide enough details, fortunately you asked for "ideas" not the real cause).

Ansible `shell` module does not run the command you specify prepended with `sudo` - it runs the whole shell session with `sudo`, so the command doesn't match what you configured in `sudoers`.

Either allow all commands to be run with elevated privileges for the Ansible user, or use `raw` module instead of `shell`.

Comment: Thank you @techraf. I am curious, what is the difference between the shell module and raw module? How would my utilize the raw module to my advantage in this case?

Comment: `shell` is a module written in Python, which calls shell with the given command as a command-string, like `bash -c "echo test"` (but in reality a bit more complex). `raw` runs the given command directly in SSH session (no Python involved).

Comment: If I use the raw module, can the playbook stay the same, except for swapping in 'raw:' where I currently have 'shell:'?

Comment: `raw` almost works. but it still changes the command so strict command definitions in `sudoers` will not work.  `Sorry, user someuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-pwugospwnreotvhdmhxzcolhmivrncfr; somecommand' as root on someserver.`